# How does the return function work in recursion?

Tags: python

I don't get how the return statements work in any recursive function (in python). Can someone please give me a few basic examples as to what's going on, when you're returning "stuff" in a recursive function?

Comment: The best way to see how they work is to just plug a number in and follow the code by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is an elegant programming style in which a function calls itself in a simpler form, until the simplest form is achieved.

This simplest form is called the 'base case' (in the following example, the base case is `if n == 1: return 1` because for factorials, 1 is the simplest case you need to reach) which is a test to see whether or not the input is in its simplest possible state.

The other part of a recursive function is the 'recursive case', which is simplifying the function further (in the following example, `n * factorial(n-1)` is the recursive case because it is simplifying the function using `n-1`).

A simple, recursive factorial function:

```
def factorial(n): # only works for positive numbers
    if n == 1: return 1 # base case
    return n * factorial(n-1) # recursive case; only executed if the above is not
                              # executed because 'return' stops a function
```

A factorial is the multiplication of all numbers up to and including `n`.

Let's break this apart:
`factorial(4)`:

1. Is `n` 1? No, so `return n * factorial(n-1)`
2. `4 * factorial(4-1)` = `4 * factorial(3)`
3. Is `n` 1? No, so `return n * factorial(n-1)`
4. `3 * factorial(3-1)` = `3 * factorial(2)`
5. Is `n` 1? No, so `return n * factorial(n-1)`
6. `2 * factorial(2-1)` = `2 * factorial(1)`
7. Is `n` 1? YES, so `return 1`

Now let's trace the calls:

Steps 1, 3, 5 are just checks, so they don't really return anything:

- Step 2: `factorial(4) = 4 * factorial(3)`
- Step 4: `factorial(3) = 3 * factorial(2)`
- Step 6: `factorial(2) = 2 * factorial(1)`
- Step 7: `factorial(1) = 1`.

Thus, tracing the `return` statements:
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24, which is the factorial of 4.

Answer (score 1):

When a function makes a recursive call, control passes *into* the called function. When a function returns, control passes *out* of that function to the one that called it. This is how an interactive debugger describes what is happening: step *in* to a function, step *over* each statement, step *out* of the function.

The usual bookkeeping for function calls is the structure called a stack. We're supposed to imagine a stack of plates that rest on a spring. Each invocation (call) of a function is one more plate "pushed" onto the "top" of the stack. Each return from a function "pops" that invocation off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that uses indentation to represent the recursive calls (by measuring the depth of the stack)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def factorial(n):
...     print('{:{}}factorial({})'.format('', len(inspect.stack()), n))
...     retval = 1 if n == 1 else n * factorial(n-1)
...     print('{:{}}return {}'.format('', len(inspect.stack()), retval))
...     return retval
... 
>>> factorial(5)
  factorial(5)
   factorial(4)
    factorial(3)
     factorial(2)
      factorial(1)
      return 1
     return 2
    return 6
   return 24
  return 120
120
```